# How to implement suggestion with paginated data - frontend

Tags: javascript

I have a list of users that is loaded in batches from server. How can I show suggestions as the email id is being typed without the data fully loaded.

Comment: This is an extremely broad question with many things to consider and specific to your case, it's not really a great fit for the Q&A format of StackOverflow. For example, can you edit the backend, what endpoints you have, what kind of suggestion system do you need (exact specs) etc.

Comment: I am gettings users / channels list from slack api as the user types the email id, matching email suggestions should be shown